# select last message of conversation for each conversation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

my query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM messages_status mst
       INNER JOIN messages msg 
             ON mst.msg_id=msg.id
 WHERE mst.user_id = 1 
       AND mst.status NOT IN (0,3)
ORDER BY 
       msg.created_at DESC
```

will show up in this sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be010/1/0

You have there the 2 tables: messages and message_status
first contains message data like content, sender_id, created time, and conversation id.
Second has specific user msg status, is it read or deleted.

**I want to get the last message of each conversation**

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
SELECT *
  FROM messages_status mst
       INNER JOIN (SELECT messages.* FROM messages INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT sender_ID,conv_id,MAX(created_at) as maxtime FROM messages
                    GROUP BY sender_ID,conv_id) as t1 ON
                    t1.sender_id = messages.sender_id AND t1.conv_id = messages.conv_id AND 
                    t1.maxtime = messages.created_at) msg 
                    ON mst.msg_id=msg.id
WHERE mst.user_id = 1 AND mst.status NOT IN (0,3)
ORDER BY msg.created_at DESC
```

this is the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be010/65/0)

Comment: Thanks! But any idea why I get 2 rows per conv instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be010/116

This is the query which you can use mostly:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT messages.id as id, 
messages.conv_id as conv_id,
max(messages.created_at) as created_at FROM messages,messages_status
WHERE messages.id = messages_status.msg_id
AND messages_status.user_id = 1 
AND messages_status.status NOT IN (0,3)
GROUP BY messages.conv_id) max_created
INNER JOIN messages 
ON messages.created_at = max_created.created_at
INNER JOIN  messages_status mst 
ON mst.msg_id=max_created.id
GROUP BY messages.conv_id
ORDER BY max_created.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you  an see in the results you get only one conversatiin message, there are 2 conversations

Comment: Ok.. Figured out what I was doing wrong. Edited the above query and Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked  **get the last message of each conversation**
You may try this

```
select *
from messages msg
inner join
(
  select max(created_at) created_at
  from messages
  group by conv_id
) m2
  on msg.created_at = m2.created_at

Inner JOIN messages_status mst ON msg.id=mst.msg_id 
WHERE mst.user_id = 1 AND mst.status NOT IN (0,3)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be010/89

Answer (score 1):

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be010/98)**

Query:

```
SELECT msg.*
FROM messages_status mst
INNER JOIN messages msg ON mst.msg_id=msg.id
LEFT JOIN messages ms2
 ON ms2.conv_id = msg.conv_id
 AND ms2.created_at > msg.created_at
WHERE mst.user_id = 1 
 AND mst.status NOT IN (0,3)
 AND ms2.created_at is null
```

Result:

```
| ID | SENDER_ID | CONV_ID |       CONTENT |                   CREATED_AT |                   UPDATED_AT |
|----|-----------|---------|---------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|
| 16 |         3 |       3 |         hy :) | March, 26 2014 16:38:17+0000 | March, 26 2014 16:38:17+0000 |
| 14 |         1 |       1 | kjhkjhkjh  kl | March, 26 2014 16:16:25+0000 | March, 26 2014 16:16:25+0000 |
```

Comment: Only solution that doesn't involve a second query. Works like a charm.